# HTTP Headers and Data response, how to decode % in data?

Tags: c++, qt, http

I am producing a HTTP response from an Qt 5.15.2 application, the response is typically something like:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: XMLMPAM
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Date: Sun, 24 Jan 2021 07:56:45 GMT
Content-Length: 65
Connection: Closed
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>{%22msgType%22:%22hb%22}</body></html>
```

Here is the code that produces this:

```
static const QString scstrLineTerm("\r\n");
QString strWrapper("<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>" + arybytData + "</body></html>")
       ,strDateTime(dtUTC.toString("ddd, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss") + " GMT")
       ,strDataLength(QString::number(strWrapper.length()))
       ,strHTTP = QString("HTTP/1.1 200 OK%1"
                          "Server: XMLMPAM%2"
                          "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *%3"
                          "Date: %4%5"
                          "Content-Length: %6%7"
                          "Connection: Closed%8"
                          "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8%9"
                          "%10%11"
                          "%12").arg(scstrLineTerm
                                    ,scstrLineTerm
                                    ,scstrLineTerm
                                    ,strDateTime, scstrLineTerm
                                    ,strDataLength, scstrLineTerm
                                    ,scstrLineTerm
                                    ,scstrLineTerm
                                    ,scstrLineTerm, scstrLineTerm
                                    ,strWrapper);
```

This is the URL from the browser that goes with the response:

```
http://localhost:8123/?{%22msgType%22:%22hb%22}
```

The browser gets the response:

```
{%22msgType%22:%22hb%22}
```

What I want is a response without the escape codes so it looks like:

```
{"msgType":"hb"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

```
QString strWrapper("<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>" + QUrl::fromPercentEncoding(arybytData) + "</body></html>")
       ,strDateTime(dtUTC.toString("ddd, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss") + " GMT")
       ,strDataLength(QString::number(strWrapper.length()))
       ,strHTTP;
strHTTP = QString("HTTP/1.1 200 OK%1"
                  "Server: XMLMPAM%2"
                  "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *%3"
                  "Date: %4%5"
                  "Content-Length: %6%7"
                  "Connection: Closed%8"
                  "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8%9"
                  "%10%11"
                  "%12").arg(scstrLineTerm
                            ,scstrLineTerm
                            ,scstrLineTerm
                            ,strDateTime, scstrLineTerm
                            ,strDataLength, scstrLineTerm
                            ,scstrLineTerm
                            ,scstrLineTerm
                            ,scstrLineTerm, scstrLineTerm
                            ,strWrapper);
```

Response:

```
{"msgType":"hb"}
```